# Looking for a flash recorder like Nimbb or WebFLVRecorder that supports caching

Tags: caching, video, webcam, flv, h.264

I'm currently using WebFLVrecorder, but in low bandwidth situations the quality of the video is pretty low because so many frames are lost.  Is there a solution out there (perhaps even non-flash) that allows for caching onto the hard drive for subsequent non-real-time transmission?

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://hdfvr.com . It is a commercial video recording solution developed in Flash. It can record to both .flv and .mp4 files and when used with Wowza and the Wowza Transcoder it can record MP4 files with AAC audio and H.264 video.